I can’t turn square face into rounded edge


The first pic is the front face of a cola bottle I modeled and the second one I modeled it with a flat plane then extrude it and mirror. The result is really bad, and I got no idea how to fix it.

What you need to do is delete one half of your object on the x-axis so you only have half of the"outline" of the bottle, then add a screw modifier.
